# correct indentation json in angular using JsonPipe

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a mock JS object that i would like to display as JSON. This is the object

```
  public theObject: any = {
    additionalProp1: {
      additional_data: {
        additionalProp1: 'string',
        additionalProp2: 'string',
        additionalProp3: 'string',
      },
      type: 'string',
      value: 'string',
    },
    additionalProp2: {
      additional_data: {
        additionalProp1: 'string',
        additionalProp2: 'string',
        additionalProp3: 'string',
      },
      type: 'string',
      value: 'string',
    },
    additionalProp3: {
      additional_data: {
        additionalProp1: 'string',
        additionalProp2: 'string',
        additionalProp3: 'string',
      },
      type: 'string',
      value: 'string',
    },
  };
```

that is located in the .ts file. In the HTML i have this to display the data as JSON:

```
<div class="card-scrollable" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
    <pre>{{ theObject | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

which works fine but the indentation is not correct as can be seen here:

[image]

I was hoping to get the indentation somewhat like this:

[image]

I read the [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) of JsonPipe but could not find an option that enables me to get the indentation correctly.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`json`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/39935ee0057d6a99bec75179a9ec67c063025fa6/packages/common/src/pipes/json_pipe.ts#L36) pipe is a transform function with a single line:

```js
transform(value: any): string {
  return JSON.stringify(value, null, 2);
}
```

You could write a simple function to increase the `space` argument of [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function. Try the following

Controller

```
toString(value: any) {
  return JSON.stringify(value, null, 4);     // <-- `space` increased from 2 to 4
}
```

Template

```html
<div class="card-scrollable" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
  <pre>{{ toString(theObject) }}</pre>
</div>
```

Or if you'd prefer using a pipe, you could implement your own with the modified `space` argument value.

Comment: Very smart observation, thanks a lot! I will start looking at implementation due to you from now on!