# How to display json using pre tag in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How to display formatted json string inside dynamically created Div using forEach loop.

My code -

```
    <div id="container_div">
    </div>
        
     $scope.getJSON=()=>{
      var settings = {
      "url": "https://api/json,
      "method": "GET",
      "timeout": 0,
       };
        
       $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
       var container = document.getElementById("container_div");
       container.innerHTML="";
       var content="";
       response.jsonData.forEach((data)=>{
       var json = JSON.parse(data.json);
       var formatted = JSON.stringify(json).split(",").join("<br/>");
       var removeSlash = formatted.split("/").join('replace');
       content += `<div class="col-md-12 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white" style="max-height: 500px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto">
<p>${JSON.stringify(removeSlash)}</p> </div>`;
      container.innerHTML += content;
      });
      $scope.$apply();
       }).fail(function (error){
           console.log(error);
       });
       }
      }
```

The only problem I am facing currently is- I am getting "/" in the final output div like-

```
"{\"dob\":\"2021-03-17T19:32:24.163Z\"
\"codes\":[]
\"name\":\"Rahul\"}
{\"codes\":[]
\"type\":{\"codes\":[]}
\"name\":\"Rahul\"}]   
\"someDate\":\"2021-03-17T19:42:56.934Z\"}"
```

I have tried removing the slash using split and join but that's not working.
How can I resolve this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869610/correct-indentation-json-in-angular-using-jsonpipe

Comment: @MikNiller - that answer is for angular, not angularjs

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be parsing the response from the server most likely, rather than iterating the response and parsing individual elements.

Secondly, you say you're getting a "/" in your output, but I only see "\" - which is what JSON.stringify will do to escape quotes in a JSON string.

But the real call for help here is the way you're manipulating the DOM. In angularJS, you don't search the DOM for elements and add innerHTML. You use the built-in angular methods. Here is an example

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"
    }).then(function(response) {
      $scope.todos = response.data;
    })
  }]);
```

```css
li {
  color: #666;
}

.completed {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-class="{'completed':todo.completed}">{{todo.title}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `JSON.stringify` in template string

```js
let s = "{\"dob\":\"2021-03-17T19:32:24.163Z,\"codes\":[],\"name\":\"Rahul\"},{\"codes\":[],\"type\":{\"codes\":[]},\"name\":\"Rahul\"}],\"someDate\":\"2021-03-17T19:42:56.934Z\"}";
s = s.replace(/,/g, "<br/>");
document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = `<div class="col-md-12 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white" style="max-height: 500px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto">
<p>${s}</p> </div>`;
```

Comment: I tried without stringify also I am getting backslash in the output

Comment: @Amara please share [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)